# laravel 8 Composite primary key with updateOrCreate

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-8

I just want to ask why upset method in eloquant ORM we can update records with "Composite" primary keys, and we can not do that with updateOrCreate ? !!! I have a table that users insert and update in most of times and it's not a good idea to have one Primary Key "id" !!

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using the model events you can Mute events for your action to avoid the error.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#muting-events

```
ModelName::withoutEvents(function (){
    ModelName::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => 'test',
            'second_id' => 0
        ],
        [
            'data' => 'some data'
        ]
    );
});
```